# Deleting array from collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am facing an issue in deleting an array from db.

[image]

I want to `delete` the `[2] array` with its `id` as condition.

I have tried many things, but none give results as expected.

```
db.users.update({ '_id': ObjectId("53689fa45bac9757f81fbb77")},{ '$pull' : { 'injury._id': ObjectId("5379974ac76d005c2d00005c") } })
```

Comment: you want to do it with an update query or directly in your GUI (it looks like you use Robomongo) ?

Comment: i want it with an update query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator to remove the element you do not want:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "injury._id": ObjectId("53760d9820b6ee683000005c") },
    { 
        "$pull": { 
            "injury": { "_id": ObjectId("53760d9820b6ee683000005c") }
        }
    }
)
```

Forgive me if the actual `_id` values do not match as you posted a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, something like this should work

```
.update(..., { $pull: { injury: {_id: YOUR_ID } } })
```

The format of [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) is

```
$pull: { arrayName: { array item query } }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `unset()` if you're using PHP